# Performance issue in Hibernate while using session.merge

Tags: java, performance, hibernate

I have a method :

```
// method
Session session = Context.getHibernateSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
private void method(TableAList AList) {
for(A a : AList) {
session.merge(a);
}
tx.commit();
}
```

When AList contains more than 40 to 50 objects of table A, it's becoming very slow and taking lots of time to complete. How to resolve this issue?

Entity A:

```
/**
 * The persistent class for the A database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="A")
public class A implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private APK id;

@Column(name="ACTION_CD")
private String actionCd;

@Column(name="AD_LMT")
private BigDecimal adLmt;

@Temporal( TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="BEG_DT")
private Date begDt;

@Column(name="BEG_TIME")
private String begTime;

@Column(name="CST_RMA")
private BigDecimal cstRma;

private String deal;

@Temporal( TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="END_DT")
private Date endDt;

@Column(name="END_TIME")
private String endTime;

@Temporal( TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="ENT_DT")
private Date entDt;

@Column(name="ENT_TIME")
private String entTime;

@Column(name="ITM_CD")
private String itmCd;

@Column(name="PC_TP")
private String pcTp;

@Temporal( TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="PLUC_DT")
private Date plucDt;

@Column(name="PREV_PERM_RET")
private BigDecimal prevPermRet;

@Column(name="PROMO_KEY_VALUE")
private String promoKeyValue;

@Column(name="RET_PRC")
private BigDecimal retPrc;

public A() {
}

public APK getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(APK id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getActionCd() {
    return this.actionCd;
}

public void setActionCd(String actionCd) {
    this.actionCd = actionCd;
}

public BigDecimal getAdLmt() {
    return this.adLmt;
}

public void setAdLmt(BigDecimal adLmt) {
    this.adLmt = adLmt;
}

public Date getBegDt() {
    return this.begDt;
}

public void setBegDt(Date begDt) {
    this.begDt = begDt;
}

public String getBegTime() {
    return this.begTime;
}

public void setBegTime(String begTime) {
    this.begTime = begTime;
}

public BigDecimal getCstRma() {
    return this.cstRma;
}

public void setCstRma(BigDecimal cstRma) {
    this.cstRma = cstRma;
}

public String getDeal() {
    return this.deal;
}

public void setDeal(String deal) {
    this.deal = deal;
}

public Date getEndDt() {
    return this.endDt;
}

public void setEndDt(Date endDt) {
    this.endDt = endDt;
}

public String getEndTime() {
    return this.endTime;
}

public void setEndTime(String endTime) {
    this.endTime = endTime;
}

public Date getEntDt() {
    return this.entDt;
}

public void setEntDt(Date entDt) {
    this.entDt = entDt;
}

public String getEntTime() {
    return this.entTime;
}

public void setEntTime(String entTime) {
    this.entTime = entTime;
}

public String getItmCd() {
    return this.itmCd;
}

public void setItmCd(String itmCd) {
    this.itmCd = itmCd;
}

public String getPcTp() {
    return this.pcTp;
}

public void setPcTp(String pcTp) {
    this.pcTp = pcTp;
}

public Date getPlucDt() {
    return this.plucDt;
}

public void setPlucDt(Date plucDt) {
    this.plucDt = plucDt;
}

public BigDecimal getPrevPermRet() {
    return this.prevPermRet;
}

public void setPrevPermRet(BigDecimal prevPermRet) {
    this.prevPermRet = prevPermRet;
}

public String getPromoKeyValue() {
    return this.promoKeyValue;
}

public void setPromoKeyValue(String promoKeyValue) {
    this.promoKeyValue = promoKeyValue;
}

public BigDecimal getRetPrc() {
    return this.retPrc;
}

public void setRetPrc(BigDecimal retPrc) {
    this.retPrc = retPrc;
}
}
```

APK:
    @Embeddable
    public class APK implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name="SKU_NUM")
private String skuNum;

@Column(name="PRC_ZONE_CD")
private String prcZoneCd;

@Column(name="PRC_GRP_CD")
private String prcGrpCd;

@Column(name="PC_NUM")
private String pcNum;

public APK() {
}
public String getSkuNum() {
    return this.skuNum;
}
public void setSkuNum(String skuNum) {
    this.skuNum = skuNum;
}
public String getPrcZoneCd() {
    return this.prcZoneCd;
}
public void setPrcZoneCd(String prcZoneCd) {
    this.prcZoneCd = prcZoneCd;
}
public String getPrcGrpCd() {
    return this.prcGrpCd;
}
public void setPrcGrpCd(String prcGrpCd) {
    this.prcGrpCd = prcGrpCd;
}
public String getPcNum() {
    return this.pcNum;
}
public void setPcNum(String pcNum) {
    this.pcNum = pcNum;
}

public boolean equals(Object other) {
if (this == other) {
return true;
}
if (!(other instanceof APK)) {
return false;
}
APK castOther = (APK)other;
return 
this.skuNum.equals(castOther.skuNum)
&& this.prcZoneCd.equals(castOther.prcZoneCd)
&& this.prcGrpCd.equals(castOther.prcGrpCd)
&& this.pcNum.equals(castOther.pcNum);

}

public int hashCode() {
final int prime = 31;
int hash = 17;
hash = hash * prime + this.skuNum.hashCode();
hash = hash * prime + this.prcZoneCd.hashCode();
hash = hash * prime + this.prcGrpCd.hashCode();
hash = hash * prime + this.pcNum.hashCode();

return hash;
}
}
```

Comment: possible for you to post some more code, atleast entity contained in the list.

Comment: How slow is it? Use a micro benchmark framework and post your results. This is one of the frameworks - http://labs.carrotsearch.com/junit-benchmarks.html

Comment: When merging everything is added to the first level cache. Each time you merge all the objects in the first level cache are checked if they need to be persisted. So the more objects you add, the longer that check will take. To fix after each X iterations, do a flush and clear of the EntityManager.

Comment: but i can flush it only after tx.commit(); in a finally block, not before that. is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: You are wrong. You can flush whenever you want... A flush isn't a commit.